Do fruits have fingerprints: Can a fruit (say mango) be identified uniquely by some characteristics?
I am not a biology/botany person, so pls excuse me.
Context as asked in comments.
I want to track a fruit from the time it was plucked out of tree to the time it reaches in the hands of customer. Can customer ensure it is the same fruit what the seller claims it to be. Intermediaries can be cheaters and can also replace one with other.
Questions:
Can a fruit (say mango/kiwi) be identified uniquely by some of its characteristics? Do they have some fingerprint / facial recognition / retina scan / or some other similar way through which they can be identified uniquely?
Physical characteristics? I am not sure, but I think not: most of the kiwis look exactly same!!
Veins structure (using microscopy)? If yes, are there some mobile apps which a normal person like student use?
Similarly, can eggs be identified in some way?

Curious question, I'm imagining a "usual suspects" style lineup. Could you tell us a bit about the context, why you're expecting the science of (individual) fruit IDing might have developed, what sort of answer you're expecting here. Remember the site's requirement of showing your research when posting. There are for example ways of detecting ripe fruit, used by automatic picking systems in commercial groweries, is that what you're thinking of?

Sure. I have updated the question with context.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
